# Box2D GetPosition возвращает Infinity

Tags: javascript, typescript, box2d, pixijs

пробовал округлять но не помогает, приходит строка вместо числа

Так выглядит console.log(bodyComp.position.x.toFixed(2));

```
Infinity
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 173.46
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 2.2722952797324346e+198
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 270.03
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 Infinity
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 335.79
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 Infinity
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 462.33
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 Infinity
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 4.353618181369425e+108
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 Infinity
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 4.1637234298928753e+152
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 413.48
RenderViewSystem.ts:39 Infinity
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если шарики пнуть то они летают и у них норм позицию выдает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://github.com/likemyjob/PixiProjectArcanoid

Comment: Консоль выводит Infinity в том случае, если какое то число было поделено на ноль ([об этом написано здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-infinity)). Видать вы при каком-нибудь делении забыли поставить обработчик для этой ошибки

Comment: Или же получается слишком огромное число (числа после 1е+308 выводят тоже Infinity, так как количество разрядов в двоичном представлении не помещается в соответствующую часть стандартного 64-битного формата)

Comment: Странно позицию я беру из box2d  а там ничего не менял, только масштаб уменьшил в 100 раз, попробую уменьшить в 50 раз может бага не будет